# Whats the difference between list[-1:][0] and list[len(list)-1]?

Tags: python, list, slice

Lest say you want the last element of a python list: what is the difference between

```
myList[-1:][0]
```

and

```
myList[len(myList)-1]
```

I thought there was no difference but then I tried this

```
>>> list = [0]
>>> list[-1:][0]
0
>>> list[-1:][0] += 1
>>> list
[0]
>>> list[len(list)-1] += 1
>>> list
[1]
```

I was a little surprised...

Comment: Not sure why you're writing `list[-1:][0]`; the usual way to write that is just `list[-1]`. Also, you probably want to avoid shadowing the builtin `list()` by naming your list `list`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

if you use slicing [-1:], the returned list is a shallow-copy, not reference. so [-1:][0] modifies the new list. [len(list)-1] is reference to last object.

Answer (score 9):

`list[-1:]` creates a new list. To get the same behaviour as `list[len(list)-1]` it would have to return a view of some kind of `list`, but as I said, it creates a new temporary list. You then proceed to edit the temporary list.

Anyway, you know you can use `list[-1]` for the same thing, right?

Answer (score 3):

Slicing creates copy (shallow copy). It's often used as an shallow copy idiom.

i.e.

```
list2 = list1[:]
```

is equivalent to

```
import copy
list2 = copy.copy(list1)
```

Comment: that seems less readable/understandable than using copy...Is there a reason it's "often used"?

Comment: I agree it's less readable. Why it's used? I guess, that's because it doesn't require import.

Comment: Do you think they're avoiding the import because it takes another line of code, or because they're trying to avoid some sort of overhead (memory, load-time, etc.)?

Comment: well, for example list1[:] is an expression. copy.copy(list1) also is expression. But import copy; copy.copy(list1) isn't.

Comment: BTW. it's recognized in the documentation. http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html "Shallow copies of dictionaries can be made using dict.copy(), and of lists by assigning a slice of the entire list, for example, copied_list = original_list[:]"